# CentOs: Cannot extract downloaded tar using curl

Tags: curl, centos, gzip, tar, ls

I'm trying to download `node` using curl:

```
$>  curl https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v6.6.0.tar.xz | tar xz -C /opt
```

Now, on my Mac this works. However, in CentOs, this doesn't work:

```
$> curl https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v6.6.0.tar.xz | tar xz -C /opt
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0 14.8M    0   941    0     0   1214      0  3:33:54 --:--:--  3:33:54  1214
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child died with signal 13
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
0 14.8M    0 42083    0     0  51628      0  0:05:01 --:--:--  0:05:01 51635
curl: (23) Failed writing body (246 != 1369)
```

I don't understand what exactly is going one here.

If I split the command and do

```
$> curl https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v6.6.0.tar.xz > node.tgz
$> tar -xvf node.tgz // NOTE that I omitted the `z`
```

it works. Based on this, maybe curl unzipped the file already I tried

```
$> curl https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v6.6.0.tar.xz | tar x -C /opt
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0 14.8M    0   941    0     0   1005      0  4:18:23 --:--:--  4:18:23  1004tar: Archive is compressed. Use -J option
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
0 14.8M    0 17325    0     0  18258      0  0:14:13 --:--:--  0:14:13 18256
curl: (23) Failed writing body (428 != 1369)
```

Nope :( Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the option "-z" in tar application is waiting .gz (gunzip) format.

You should use the option "J":

```
curl https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v6.6.0.tar.xz | tar xJ -C /tmp
```

Comment: Thnx for the explanation. Do you know why it works on Mac?

Comment: The Mac uses the libarchive bsdtar, which automatically detects the compression format.